How to set up a chain proxy on Telethon
How is it convenient to set up a proxy chain locally? If I need to first connect to the Socks5 proxy, then connect to another Socks5 or HTTP proxy through this proxy, and then connect to Telegram, I have checked the documentation and it seems that there is no information on this aspect
I am not very familiar with the Telethon library and do not know how to implement it.
